# Google Cloud Endpoint 404 after deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-endpoints

Now that Google Cloud Endpoints have been opened up to all developers, I have created a Google Cloud Endpoint which works run a run locally in Eclipse debugging. But when I deploy, the live endpoint just returns an HTTP 404. My project's JSP pages run both locally and deployed. It's just the endpoints the don't work once deployed.

Anybody got any idea what I need to do to deploy cloud endpoints?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered that even though I only have one version (v1) deployed and that version was indicated as the "default" version in the app engine management console, I still had to "set" v1 as default before the API was accessible.

Comment: Can you explain what you did please?. Im having this issue too. What do you mean by "I still had to "set" v1 as default before the API was accessible"??

Comment: On appengine.google.com, go to Main > Versions. You will see a list of versions deployed (the list may, like mine, contain just one version, V1). Even though this version is the only version has it says it is the default version, I still had to press the Make Default button. After this everything started working.

Comment: ugh sadly this doesn't fix it for me. Still getting 404s

Answer (score 2):

Endpoints only supports APIs on the default app version right now.

Comment: At the risk of sounding dumb - what is the default app version?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you have to access your endpoint by making the version you deployed the default version.  For example https://yourappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/path/v2/methodname.   If you use https://someappversion.yourappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/path/v2/methodnamel, it will not work based on my experience

Comment: The default app version can be set by logging into your app engine admin client (appengine.google.com) then clicking on "Versions" in the left menu and then choosing one of the versions to be your default version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access them through the API explorer?

I had the same issue yesterday... Just happened to be using the wrong address.

Comment: Yeah I tried that - the explorer doesn't show any services etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is the V2 that is wrong. The API version does not increase with the Appengine version! These are two different versions. Try with version 1.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and my problem was I didnt generate the "Cloud Endpoint Cloud Library" in eclipse.

Once I did it, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As of App Engine 1.7.7 and earlier, this could also have been caused by forgetting to add your Endpoint class to web.xml like so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <!-- Careful! No whitespace but commas between class names. -->
        <param-value>ditto.api.CategoryEndpoint,ditto.api.PostEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, if your API is written in Java, and you're using Maven you can auto-generate an API version by adding this to your configuration for the `appengine-maven-plugin`. When deployed, the version number will be automatically updated, and the deployed version will be set as the only current running version of your API:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <deploy.projectId>my-gcp-project-name</deploy.projectId>
      <deploy.version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</deploy.version>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The relevant line is `<deploy.version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</deploy.version>` (`GCLOUD_CONFIG` is the actual value you need - it's recognised as a special variable when you deploy)

---